# grouping List of Objects and counting using Java collection

Tags: java, collections, count, grouping

Which Java Collection class is better to group the list of objects?

I have a list of messages from users like below:

```
aaa hi
bbb hello
ccc Gm
aaa  Can?
CCC   yes
ddd   No
```

From this list of message object I want to count and display `aaa(2)+bbb(1)+ccc(2)+ddd(1)`. Any code help?

Comment: A `HashMap<String, Integer>` has been used for similar purposes many times before (assuming you store `aaa` as String objects; otherwise you will want to use another type than String as key, just make sure that type implements `hashCode()` and `equals()`).

Comment: Hi, thanks for many answers but nothing solving my problem...    i have a list like Hashset<String> messages = new HashSet();    messages contain list of user nd message column as above. So i have to extract and display count  with user.

Comment: You’ll have to show us some code, this will be the most precise way to describe your design. Preferably produce i [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us.

Comment: Code is in this link        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39217924/parse-xml-using-java-stax-count-number-of-content-tags

Comment: That’s a lot of code over there …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the pieces together from a couple of the other answers, adapting to your code from the other question and fixing a few trivial errors:

```
    // as you want a sorted list of keys, you should use a TreeMap
    Map<String, Integer> stringsWithCount = new TreeMap<>();
    for (Message msg : convinfo.messages) {
        // where ever your input comes from: turn it into lower case,
        // so that "ccc" and "CCC" go for the same counter
        String item = msg.userName.toLowerCase();
        if (stringsWithCount.containsKey(item)) {
            stringsWithCount.put(item, stringsWithCount.get(item) + 1);
        } else {
            stringsWithCount.put(item, 1);
        }
    }
    String result = stringsWithCount
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + '(' + entry.getValue() + ')')
            .collect(Collectors.joining("+"));
    System.out.println(result);
```

This prints:

```
aaa(2)+bbb(1)+ccc(2)+ddd(1)
```

Comment: Sorry about the inconsistent style. You may do it all with loops or everything with streams, depending on your taste and Java version.

Comment: hey thanks its working.... but I am not able to do it with stream (java 7/8 ) feature... dont know why still it gives error in eclipse .. So i used old way like map entry and traverse its working !

Comment: how to take the last result out of this??

Comment: Er, I believe it’s outsude the question. Fortunately it’s quite easy, so easy you could probably find out yourself: `stringsWithCount` is declared a `TreeMap`. `TreeMap` is an implementation of the `SortedMap` interface (which is why @GhostCar and @NicolasFilotto suggested it). In the API doc of `SortedMap` you notice that one of the nine methods is `lastKey()`. So `stringsWithCount.lastKey()` will return `"WVU"`. If you pass this into `stringsWithCount.get()`, you will get the count too (that is, 1 in this case).

Comment: I tried that stringWithCount.lastKey() is printing me like G_LO
G_LO
G_LO
WVU
WVU
WVU
WVU
WVU
WVU

Comment: That looks right to me. Just let me guess, you are processing 9 `convinfo` (conversation information) objects, or you are processing the same `convinfo` object 9 times with further messages having been added in between? Which gives the 9 result strings you quoted (separated by space in your comment, probably by newline in your actual output). The last `username` in each of those 9 results is exactly `G_LO G_LO G_LO WVU WVU WVU WVU WVU WVU` — the printout you got.

Comment: yah got it I places the code in wrong place to loop 9times .. now working fine...

Answer (score 4):

You can use  `Map<String, Integer>` where the keys represent the individual strings, and the map value is the counter for each one.

So you can do something like:

```
// where ever your input comes from: turn it into lower case,
// so that "ccc" and "CCC" go for the same counter
String item = userinput.toLowerCase(); 

// as you want a sorted list of keys, you should use a TreeMap
Map<String, Integer> stringsWithCount = new TreeMap<>();
for (String item : str) {
  if (stringsWithCount.contains(item)) {
    stringsWithCount.put(item, stringsWithCount.get(item)+1));
  } else {
    stringsWithCount.put(item, 0);
  }
}
```

And then you can iterate the map when done:

```
for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : stringsWithCount.entrySet()) {
```

and build your result string.

That was like the old-school implementation; if you want to be fancy and surprise your teachers, you can go for the Java8/lambda/stream solution.
( where i wouldn't recommend that unless you really invest the time to completely understand the following solution; as this is untested from my side)

```
Arrays.stream(someListOrArrayContainingItems)
  .collect(Collectors
     .groupingBy(s -> s, TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
  .entrySet()
  .stream()
  .flatMap(e -> Stream.of(e.getKey(), String.valueOf(e.getValue())))
  .collect(Collectors.joining())
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a [MultiSet](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained) from guava. That collection type is *tailor-made* for this kind of task:

```
MultiSet<String> multiSet = new MultiSet<>();
for (String line : lines) { // somehow you read the lines
    multiSet.add(line.split(" ")[0].toLowerCase());
}
boolean first = true;
for (Multiset.Entry<String> entry : multiset.entrySet()) {
    if (!first) {
        System.out.println("+");
    }
    first = false;
    System.out.print(entry.getElement() + "(" + entry.getCount() + ")");            
}
```

Comment: Hint: you should make it more explicit that one needs to use a 3rd party library for your solution. And I am also wondering if the multiset will treat "ccc" as "CCC" - as given in his example input.

Comment: I would reword: he doesn't **need** to. Maybe he can; but the problem can be solved without the **need** to turn to a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you use Java 8, it could be something like this using the Stream API:

```
List<Message> messages = ...;
// Convert your list as a Stream
// Extract only the login from the Message Object
// Lowercase the login to be able to group ccc and CCC together
// Group by login using TreeMap::new as supplier to sort the result alphabetically
// Convert each entry into login(count)
// Join with a +
String result =
    messages.stream()
        .map(Message::getLogin)
        .map(String::toLowerCase)
        .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                Function.identity(), TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()
            )
        )
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + '(' + entry.getValue() + ')')
        .collect(Collectors.joining("+"))
System.out.println(result);
```

**Output:**

```
aaa(2)+bbb(1)+ccc(2)+ddd(1)
```

If you want to group your messages by login and have the result as a collection, you can proceed as next:

```
Map<String, List<Message>> groupedMessages = 
    messages.stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                message -> message.getLogin().toLowerCase(), 
                TreeMap::new, 
                Collectors.toList()
            )
        );
```