# How to Compare element of Arraylist<Integer>

Tags: java, collections

I wrote below code to get duplicate elements from Arraylist. My aerospikePIDs list doesn't have any duplicate value but still when I am executing below code it is reading if condition.

```
ArrayList<Integer> aerospikePIDs = new ArrayList<Integer>();    

ArrayList<Integer> duplicates = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    boolean flag;
    for(int j=0;j<aerospikePIDs.size();j++) {
        for(int k=1;k<aerospikePIDs.size();k++) {
            if(aerospikePIDs.get(j)==aerospikePIDs.get(k)) {
            duplicates.add(aerospikePIDs.get(k));
            flag=true;
            }
            if(flag=true)
System.out.println("duplicate elements for term " +searchTerm+duplicates);
    }   
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your inner loop should start from `j + 1` (not from `1`), otherwise when `j = 1` (second iteration of j), for `k = 1` (first iteration of k for j value equals to 1).

```
aerospikePIDs.get(j)==aerospikePIDs.get(k)
```

returns `true`.

So the code should be:

```
ArrayList<Integer> aerospikePIDs = new ArrayList<Integer>();    

ArrayList<Integer> duplicates = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int j = 0; j < aerospikePIDs.size(); j++) {
    for (int k = j + 1; k < aerospikePIDs.size(); k++) {
        if (aerospikePIDs.get(j)==aerospikePIDs.get(k)) {
            duplicates.add(aerospikePIDs.get(k));
            System.out.println("duplicate elements for term " +searchTerm+duplicates);
        }
    }   
}
```

Note: the flag is not necessary, because if you addeda duplicate you can print it directly in the if, without defining new unnecessary variables and code.

Comment: flag is unnecessary. I updated the answer removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Use higher level abstractions:

1. Push all list elements into a `Map<Integer, Integer>` - key is the entry in your PIDs list, value is a counter. The corresponding loop simply checks "key present? yes - increase counter; else, add key with counter 1".
2. In the end, you can iterate that map, and each entry that has a counter > 1 ... has duplicates in your list; and you even get the number of duplicates for *free*.

And questions/answers that show you nice ways to do such things ... are posted here on almost daily basis. You can start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39201942/grouping-list-of-objects-and-counting-using-java-collection/39202053#39202053) for example; and you only need to adapt from "String" key to "Integer" key.

Really: when working with collections, your first step is always: find the **most highlevel** way of getting things done - instead of sitting down and writing such error-prone low-level code as you just did.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating using the same arraylist. You are checking every data in inner for loop, for sure it will display duplicates.